# copy release aar file after succeful build

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, aar

when building an aar file using gradle, how can I copy the created release aar to some other directory ?
(I do not want to change the default output dir just to copy the release file )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you are not using any flavors, and you are not changing the AAR name, you can use something like the following task:

```
task copyAAR(type: Copy) {
    from('build/outputs/aar')
    into('/path/to/desired/output/dir')
    include(project.name + '-release.aar')
}
```

If you changed the AAR name, replace 'project.name' with that name.

Comment: thanks, how do I tell gradle to do that every successful release build ?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by that... it can't happen as part of the assemble task as it is a pre-requisite for the copyAAR task. What you can do is either call 'gradle assemble copyAAR' so that it assembles it and then copies it over, or make copyAAR depend on assemble (copyAAR.dependsOn assemble), and then just call 'gradle copyAAR' and the assemble will happen too. If you want it to happen when you hit the Gradle sync button in Android Studio, then I don't know how to do that one, but it should be possible to tell the assemble task to execute this at the end.